# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3.drivers' (File Compiled with pyinstaller), but working fine as uncompiled

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyttsx

I compiled my program using pyinstaller, python file working fine when not compiled, but throwing the error when i compiled & tested it.

This is the full error, I think this might be because of pyinstaller

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
  File "c:\python37\lib\weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: 'sapi5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "song_dl.py", line 25, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
  File "site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
  File "site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
  File "site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3.drivers'
[1072] Failed to execute script song_dl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [When things went wrong](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html) section of the docs
And in particular, the [Listing hidden imports](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports)

It looks like pyinstaller is not able to "know" it need to add this particular module, so you need to specify it explicitly

probably something like

```
$ pyinstaller --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers song_dl.py
```

Comment: This is incorrect: it is not --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers, but just pyttsx3   , because that is how the module is called.

Answer (score 7):

First, go to the folder where your python.exe file is installed, then go to this directory:

> \Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks

You have to install pyinstaller first before going into the directory.
Then look in the hooks folder and see if there is a file named:

> hook-pyttsx3.py

There is a strong possibility that the file might not be present.
So, you have to create `hook-pyttsx3.py` in the hooks folder and in the file you have to write:

```py
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2013-2020, PyInstaller Development Team.
#
# Distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License (version 2
# or later) with exception for distributing the bootloader.
#
# The full license is in the file COPYING.txt, distributed with this software.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: (GPL-2.0-or-later WITH Bootloader-exception)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


""" pyttsx3 imports drivers module based on specific platform. Fount at https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/6 """


hiddenimports = [
    'pyttsx3.drivers',
    'pyttsx3.drivers.dummy',
    'pyttsx3.drivers.espeak',
    'pyttsx3.drivers.nsss',
    'pyttsx3.drivers.sapi5', ]
```

Save the file.
Then run your code.
The problem will be solved (at least it worked for me.)
This problem came because pyinstaller is not updated officially to use python 3.8 fully, so hooks of some modules are missing

Comment: i can't just make a hooks dir and point pyinstaller to it using `--aditional-hooks-dir=hooksdir` ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @Lakshya is correct but limited to the Windows environment.

For the users using Anaconda, the path changes. And for the simplicity for the new users, here is the updated path.

Here, I am using a virtual environment called `voice`, so its in `envs/voice/` along with `python3.7`. These may vary according to your local path.

```
/anaconda3/envs/voice/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks
```

And if you are not using a virtual environment the it will look like,

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks
```

And then simply add the file `hook-pyttsx3.py`.

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2013-2020, PyInstaller Development Team.
#
# Distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License (version 2
# or later) with exception for distributing the bootloader.
#
# The full license is in the file COPYING.txt, distributed with this software.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: (GPL-2.0-or-later WITH Bootloader-exception)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


""" pyttsx3 imports drivers module based on specific platform. Fount at https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/6 """


hiddenimports = [
    'pyttsx3.drivers',
    'pyttsx3.drivers.dummy',
    'pyttsx3.drivers.espeak',
    'pyttsx3.drivers.nsss',
    'pyttsx3.drivers.sapi5', ]
```