# Python Standalone Executable file does not run and shows error in Command Prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

As I am new in Python, I made a VOICE ASSISTANT by Python in Pycharm. I only write the code and run I in the pycharm, it ran smoothly. I haven't made any GUI for it. I just converted the code in the EXE file by using the Pyinstaller. when I run the exe file, it has shown me this error in Command Prompt.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
  File "c:\users\faizan\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\weakref.py", line 131, in 
__getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: 'sapi5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
  File "site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
  File "site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 936, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3.drivers'
[2844] Failed to execute script s
```

I think, this the problem of many beginners. Please Help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3.drivers' (File Compiled with pyinstaller), but working fine as uncompiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58133083/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyttsx3-drivers-file-compiled-with-pyins)

Answer (score 1):

Use hidden import to specify the module while creating exe,

```
$ pyinstaller --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers yourscript.py
```