# modulenotfounderror no module named 'pyttsx3.drivers.sapi'

Tags: python

```
import pyttsx3

Assistant = pyttsx3.init('sapi.5')
voices = Assistant.getProperty('voices')
print(voices)
Assistant.setProperty('voices',voices(1).id)
def Speak(audio):
    print("   ")
    Assistant.say(audio)
    print("   ")
    Assistant.runAndWait()

Speak('Hello sir, I am Y.P.A')
```

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: please make sure to make things clear
-no questions 
- no error message

Comment: Guys I am a begginner idk how to use stackoverflow I am new

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w85nrwA7Erq4SwPbUSraB_WFhsiSgjWc/view?usp=sharing now you can see the full error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3.drivers' (File Compiled with pyinstaller), but working fine as uncompiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58133083/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyttsx3-drivers-file-compiled-with-pyins)

Comment: No but thanks it doesen't work

Comment: :((((((((((((((

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.